Stopping criterion for single tree growth in randomForest() in R?
what is the stopping criterion for a single tree in the forst if the function randomForest() from library(randomForest) is used in a basic way in R:
library(randomForest)
randomForest(y ~ ., data = data_train, ntree = 500)


There is a min count of observations per leaf, which should be 5 for continuous variables and 1 (?) for categorical (or max depth or max number of splits).

Consider that the algorithm will work best in most of the cases if trees are fully grown, as discussed here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/443548

@GRowInG thanks, but what is fully grown in this case? That every terminal node contains only one observation? I didnt find any information on this in the description of the package

@Joe94 From my understanding, given the referenced question at Cross Validated, trees are fully grown by default by Breiman's algorithm implemented in randomForest::randomForest() if no pruning/stopping criterion is defined.
